# [ROS 2] layered yaml config file

Tags: ros, ros2, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I came across an example of a yaml file:

```
talker_ns:
    talker:
        ros__parameters:
            some_int: 42
            a_string: "Hello world"
            more_params:
                some_int2: 24
                some_doubles : [3.14, 2.718]
```

I have no problems with reading the *some_int* and *a_string* like this:

```
get_parameter_or("some_int", some_int, int(0));
```

However, I can't wrap my head around how to read some_int2. I tried doing it by inserting the parameter category `get_parameter_or("more_params/some_int2", some_int2, int(0));`
but it doesn't work.

I'm using rclcpp_lifecycle node (I don't know if it matters).

What is the right way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321243/%5Bros-2%5D-layered-yaml-config-file/) by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now, parameters use the `.` separator... I really don't like this and would like to change it, but a change like this will take some serious time, as we need to sort out addressing of nodes, parameters and services at the same time.

I guess your code works if you use `more_params.some_int2` instead.

EDIT: btw, you could use `ros2 param list <node name>` to see what was happening.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2